# Can I bring boxed consumer electronics in my hand luggage while traveling from the US to Doha?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, cellphones, electronic-items, hand-luggage

I will be taking my laptop in my hand luggage when going to the US. While returning, I will be bringing a new iPhone 7 Plus from the US with a power-bank charger. Is it OK to bring them in boxes in my hand luggage? Do I need to do anything or is it OK to bring them like that?

Comment: *Should* be okay. Also welcome to Travel Stack Exchange. You can take a [tour] of the site. The [help] will further answer your questions on how this site works.

Comment: Note that you **may** have to pay some kind of tax when returning to Qatar. Check with the relevant Qatari authorities.

Comment: Of course you can do this no problem.  But you may have to pay customs duty on arrival in your home country.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, you can bring all three (the laptop, smartphone and power bank charger) in your hand luggage. The fact that they are in boxes will not matter.

> Passengers are allowed to take personal electronics on board, provided
>   they fit the airline's weight and size restrictions. These items
>   include laptops, personal audio systems, hand-held gaming devices and
>   digital cameras. It can be safer to pack these items in your carry-on
>   luggage, reducing the risk they might be lost, damaged or stolen. Most
>   airlines place restrictions on passengers using electronic items
>   during take-off and landing, but passengers are allowed to carry them
>   in their luggage at all times. <sup>[Source](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/items-allowed-carryon-baggage-international-flights-54765.html)</sup>

Please note that the [TSA requires you to take the laptop out](http://blog.tsa.gov/2012/04/why-do-laptops-have-to-be-removed-when.html) of your bag while passing through security. You can put it into the bag again after passing through.

Useful addition by @CMaster:

> Note that you **may** have to pay some kind of tax when returning to
>   Qatar. Check with the relevant Qatari authorities.